# $a,b,c$ are positive real number..

Tags: inequality

$a,b,c$ are positive real number. Prove that $(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)>9(ab+bc+ca)$

I tried to it by AM-GM inequality but it is not coming

Comment: Sorry I don't know this question is already there